# Combining every 3 lines together starting on the second line, and removing first column from second and third line being combined

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am very new to unix as well as coding in general and have spent a long time trying to figure out this issue with no success. I am sure its a very simple solution but if someone can help point me in the right direction.

I have a Summary.txt file with data with the following format

```
Name criteria1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Sample12345 w x y z
Sample12345.avg l m n
Sample12345.stdn o p q
Sample98765 w2 x2 y2 z2
Sample98765.avg l2 m2 n2
Sample98765.stdn o2 p2 q2
```

etc. etc.

I am wanting to combine the three lines of the same sample numbers and only keep the first name:

```
Name criteria1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Sample12345 w x y z l m n o p q
Sample98765 w2 x2 y2 z2 l2 m2 n2 o2 p2 q2
```

etc. etc.

I have tried using sed such as
(after first making a Summary_temp.txt that contains all Sample12345.avg Sample12345.stdn etc. etc.):

`` for i in `cat Summary_temp.txt`; do sed 's/\n$i//g' Summary.txt; done ``
gives "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'sed'"

I also tried going down the path of

`paste -sd ' ' Summary.txt | sed 's/\t/\n/g10; s/\t/@/g; s/\n/\t/g' | sed 's/.\nSample.*.avg//g' | head`

I believe the closest I have gotten is:

```
cat Summary.txt | sed 's/ *| */,/g;/^$/d' | paste -d, - - - | head
```

However this starts on the 1st line so everything is off by one:

```
Name criteria1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Sample12345 w x y z Sample12345.avg l m n
Sample12345.stdn o p q Sample98765 w2 x2 y2 z2 Sample98765.avg l2 m2 n2
Sample98765.stdn o2 p2 q2 ETC ETC
```

I have tried
`head -1 Summary.txt > Summary_temp_3.txt`
so I can then add it back later.

```
sed '1d' Summary.txt > Summary_temp_4.txt
cat Summary_temp_4.txt | sed 's/ *| */,/g;/^$/d' |
  paste -d, - - - | sed 's/,.*_by_name//g | head
```

This doesn't show anything at all; I have to eventually ctrl-C, so assume it is wrong because it shouldn't take that long. Please help. I know I am very much a beginner and this may be an easily solvable dumb question but I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not especially elegant, but for the second through last line (`2,$`) pull the `N`ext line and the `N`ext line into pattern space, then `g`lobally replace any non-blank sequences following a newline:

```
sed '
2,${
N
N
s/\n[^[:blank:]]*//g
}
' Summary.txt
Name criteria1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Sample12345 w x y z l m n o p q
Sample98765 w2 x2 y2 z2 l2 m2 n2 o2 p2 q2
```

Answer (score 6):

A `paste` + `sed` approach could be (assuming the file doesn't contain `,` characters):

```
$ paste -sd '\n,,' your-file | sed 's/,[^[:blank:]]*//g'
Name criteria1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Sample12345 w x y z l m n o p q
Sample98765 w2 x2 y2 z2 l2 m2 n2 o2 p2 q2
```

Answer (score 4):

If your input data is consistent, i.e. every three lines share first field of the first line in the group, then you simply need an `awk` command -- something like this:

```shell
awk '
    NR==1{print;next} 
    NR%3==0{$1="";printf $0} 
    NR%3==1{$1="";printf $0;print ""} 
    NR%3==2{printf $0} 
   ' infile
```

Result:

```
Name criteria1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Sample12345 w x y z l m n o p q
Sample98765 w2 x2 y2 z2 l2 m2 n2 o2 p2 q2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

What you're describing might best be handled by a *hash*, since the `keys` are maintained unique. Additional key-value pairs get added to the hash as new pairs if no such `key` exists, otherwise the `values` are appended to a pre-existing `key` of the same name. As an simple example:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %h; %h.append: .split(" ", 2); END .put for %h.sort;' file
```

The above code handles a simple first-column "key", with the remainder of the line becoming the "value". For the more complicated dataset given by the OP, you need to eliminate the `.stdn` and `.avg` extensions:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %h;  \
             .split(/ \. <alpha>+ | \s+ /, :skip-empty) andthen  \
             %h.append(.[0] => .[1..*]);   \     
             END .put for %h.sort;'  file
```

Explaining more fully: Raku code is run using the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags. Before looping through lines, we `BEGIN` by declaring a hash, `%h`. Lines are then `split` on either `\. <alpha>+` (e.g. ".avg" or ".stdn"), or `\s+` on whitespace. Once split we reload `$_` with `andthen`, andthen `append` a key-value pair to `%h` hash. The `=>` "fat-arrow" syntax denotes/creates a key-value pair, as in `.[0] => .[1..*]`. The first column (index = `0`) becomes the `key`, while the remaining (index = `1..*` ) elements become the `values`.

Sample Input:

```
Name criteria1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Sample12345 w x y z
Sample12345.avg l m n
Sample12345.stdn o p q
Sample98765 w2 x2 y2 z2
Sample98765.avg l2 m2 n2
Sample98765.stdn o2 p2 q2
```

Sample Output (TAB between key and value):

```
Name    criteria1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Sample12345 w x y z l m n o p q
Sample98765 w2 x2 y2 z2 l2 m2 n2 o2 p2 q2
```

---

Finally, if you want to use the output for a CSV file, you can `join` all elements on comma (including individual values). Full answer below:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %h;  \
             .split(/ \. <alpha>+ | \s+ /, :skip-empty) andthen  \
             %h.append(.[0] => .[1..*]);   \
             END put .keys ~ "," ~ .values.map: *.join(",") for %h.sort;'  file
Sample98765,w2,x2,y2,z2,l2,m2,n2,o2,p2,q2
Sample12345,w,x,y,z,l,m,n,o,p,q
Name,criteria1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

As a double-check on the code, changing:

`.values.map: *.join(",")` to `.values.map: *.elems`

Returns the number of `value` columns, 10 for each key:

```
Name,10
Sample12345,10
Sample98765,10
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap
https://raku.org